# Sending SMS using jsp through HTTP

Tags: java, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to one web application. In that I have user registration. If user is registered I want to send one verification code to his mobile. So how to send SMS  to his mobile number. I am developing in java.  I want to send and receive SMS text messages to cellphones from a JAVA application through java. Is there any free SMS severer is available to send SMS to mobile phone 
It might sound Weird But I want to send SMS using JAVA wthout accessing any GSM modem, is that Possible, I have used Mail serve API. My idea is there any mail sevrver which is freely hosted that we can access and Send SMS anywhere?

Comment: google search: "sms gateway with API" at least 10 results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have not mentioned the location but sending an sms depends on that. As the APIs available to send SMS are generally for specific locations. From your name, I guess you belong to India and want to send SMS locally. If that is the case, then try to use the Way2SMS java library to send SMS. Here is a blog that can get you started:

http://firewithjava.blogspot.in/2012/04/way2sms-java-api-2012.html

Comment: ok.is there any other api are available for send sms free through java

Comment: with ot any login and all